# Flutter app showing only white screen on running

Tags: flutter, dart

When running an app, its just showing a white screen on my emulator and phone, but the same repo when my friend is running, is working fine. This problem started after I had pulled from master into a branch of mine. What are the possible reasons? Can anyone help?

Comment: are you running it on android-12 device ?

Comment: @HardikMehta  no. i ran it on Android 11.

Comment: isn't flutter stable channel?

Comment: please provide logs if you have after running app